# Perl Regex Substitute paragraph tag

Tags: regex, perl, expression

I am trying to use a regex to replace contents inside of paragragh tags with contents followed by br br tags

```
 s/^[<]p[>](.+)[<][/]p[>]/\1[<]br[>][<]br[>]/
```

I am getting error Unmatched [ in regex marked by <---HERE m/^[<]p>[<][

I tried changing [/] to backslash/ but im not really sure how to go about this. Thank you =]

I actually got it was

```
s/^<p>(.+)<\/p>/\1<br><br>/;
```

Comment: You need to escape the forward slash (`/`) you want to match with a backslash (`\ `) since you are using forward slashes (`/`) as separators. Also you might want to use `.+?` instead of `.+` to do non-greedy matching. Also, its generally not best to parse HTML with regular expressions, and it is better to use a regular expression parser.

Comment: Replacing `/` by `\/` should work. Says https://regex101.com/.

Comment: Please update your answer with an example that fails.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
s#(?=</p>)#<br><br>#
```

Whenever dealing with a `/`, I like to use another separator. Here I'm using `#`.

Since, you just want to append `<br><br>` and not touch anything else in `<p>..</p>`, we can use a lookahead anchor. That is what `(?=...)` does. It looks for a point after which there is a `</p>` and substitutes it with the replacement string.

Note that look-around expressions are zero-width i.e. they do not match any char.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this version of your regex:

```
s/<p>(.+?)<\/p>/\1<br><br>/si
```

I removed string start anchor `^`, it is highly possible you do not need it. `.+?` will make sure you will match the closest matching `</p>`. The `si` options will enable case-insensitive matching, and `.` will also match newline symbols.